# only enter specific characters in to a textBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textfield

I want to enter 2 decimal number to a textBox. I am using the below code which I have found in the internet in the keypress event of the textBox.

```
       if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // only allow two decimal point
        if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -2))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

In the above code first if condition id working well and I can only input numbers. But the second part which restricts only 2 decimals is not working. Please tell me what is wrong in this code.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use a MaskedTextBox.

Comment: Agree with @CodeCaster. Use a MaskedTextBox with the mask `#.##`

Comment: I tried what you said and it's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `KeyPress` for such validations. You will have always problems with some tricky editions such as replacing selected text, pasting something from the clipboard, etc.

Use `Validating` event instead or just do some custom validation when the user clicks the OK button or whatever. In these cases you can assume that the user has finished the edition and you can always validate the final text.

If the user has to enter some strict-length text, you can use `MaskedTextBox` instead.